# Heat semigroup ultracontractive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let $g(x,t)= \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4t}}$ be the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Is the standard definition now to say that this heat-semigroup $T(t)(f):=g *f(.,t)$ is ultracontractive or not? Apparently, this depends somehow on how this is defined.

So far, I thought that the answer is yes, as for $f \in L^1$ and $t>0$ we have that $g*f(.,t) \in L^{\infty},$ as $g(.,t)$ for $t>0$ is a bounded function and by Young's inequality the convolution is in $L^{\infty}$ again.

But now I read that the answer is no, as for $f \in L^2$ there is no reason why $g*f(.,t) \in L^{\infty}$ again.

I feel as if the trouble is coming from the fact that we are on unbounded domains, as otherwise $L^2 \subset L^1$ and the $L^2$ issue would not occur. (actually all references I know, are (mostly) concerned with this case).

I see arguments that speak for both answers:

It is reasonable to say yes, as boundedness of the kernel immediately implies ultracontractivity.

It is also reasonable to say no, as some generalized Sobolev inequalities do not hold in the unbounded case.

Thus, I am still wondering whether the heat semi-group is now ultracontractive or not.